# Let's retire the [sysadmin]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-cleanup-request

The [sysadmin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin) tag has a different meaning almost every question, and it never seems to refer to the actual role of a system administrator. It seems to be used for questions that have to do with the management of a system, but that has *zero* categorization usefulness - the tag for the product being managed should be applied instead.

It looks like [security](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/security) would be appropriate for many questions currently tagged [sysadmin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin). Let's do some reorganization.

Comment: I agree - not a useful tag. A lot of it can also be put into tag:Group-Policy, tag:active-directory and tag:event-log as well as your suggestion tag:security.

Comment: It really is not a useful tag. Ive seen quite a few post that do not deal with System Administration. as @Raystafarian stated the Tags tag:Group-Policy tag:Active-Directory tag:Event-Log and what you stated tag:Security would be better tags then tag:sysadmin

Comment: Concur.  It has extra disadvantage of being a readily-accesible *wrong* tag - lots of things would feel to a new user as if they should be tagged with it, without actually having anything much in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question got over forty upvotes without a single downvote, and considering that there were only a few dozen questions with the tag, I went ahead and destroyed it over the past couple days. (I also polished up the tagged questions as I went, of course.)

RIP [sysadmin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin): 2011-2016.